# Use inserted record's identity without commiting

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I have two tables: table Category and table Book

I would like to add a Category, then use its ID for inserting a book (which has a CategoryId field pointing to the table Category).

To get this info, I now commit my changes after inserting the category as it is not provided otherwise.

Is there a way to point to this category when inserting my book without commiting after inserting the category?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using LINQ? Afaik, as long as you do not call `.SaveChanges()`, the changes will not be committed.

Comment: If you're using a database that supports the concept of sequences (SQL Server **2012**, Oracle), then you could just fetch a sequence number from the database and use that. The `IDENTITY` as implemented by SQL Server will **only** ever be issued when the transaction is being committed - you **cannot** reliably determine that value before the commit is done.

Comment: I think you should update your question as your goal is to be able to roll back the Category insertion when the Book insertion fails.

Answer (score 1):

If the ID is generated by the database, then no, you can't get it until it is committed

Comment: Allright, I was helping there would be a trick to point to an entity before commiting, and the EF would do the work of saving changes and then use the generated ID. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Then it would have to do an implicit savechanges. That would have all manner of side effects :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation! it sucks though as it implies that if there were to be a problem when inserting my Book record, I could not do a rollback of the Category I inserted and saved in the DB. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a FK relationship setup. If that's the case, if you associate the `Category` and `Book` entities together - EF should be create the necessary FK's.

For example:

```
var Category = new Category();
Book.Category = Category;
context.Books.Add(Book);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Would create a book, and a category and depending on how your mapping is setup the proper fields should be set.  Can you post your model if this is not the case?